# Constructor related error in Java

Tags: java, constructor, default-constructor

I am new to Java and wrote this code. It has a simple class Box and two attributes width and length and some functions.

```
class Box 
{
    private int width;
    private int length;
    Box(int w, int l)
    {
        setWidth(w);
        setLength(l);    
    }
    public void setWidth(int width)
    {
        this.width = width;
    }
    public int getWidth() 
    {
        return width;
    }
    public void setLength(int length)
    {
        this.length = length;
    }
    public int getLength() 
    {
        return length;
    }
    void showBox()
    {
        System.out.print("Box has width:"+width +" length:"+length);
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Box mybox = new Box();
        mybox.setLength(5);
        mybox.setWidth(5);
        mybox.showBox();
    }
}
```

I am getting this error.  How can i fix it? Can someone please explain this.

```
Box.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Box()
location: class Box
                Box mybox=new Box();
```

Comment: I wanted to know the reason for error.. So somebody please explain..

Comment: Unless you're specifically intending for the constructors not to be public, make them `public`. Even if you aren't, IMO it's better to explicitly name their scope so people know it wasn't an accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the default constructor.

```
Box()
{
    length=0;
    width=0;
}
```

It so happens in Java that if you have not created any constructor then the compiler will create the default constructor itself. But if you have created the parameterized constructor and are trying to use default constructor without defining it then compiler will produce the error which you got.

Comment: Setting `length` and `width` to 0 in the constructor is a bit redundant, since they'll be initialised to those values anyway.

Comment: That is correct. But i thought it was better to write it, as he is new to Java.

Answer (score 1):

The only constuctor defined for `Box` is `Box(int w, int l)`.

Change `main()` to:

```
Box mybox = new Box(5, 5);
mybox.showBox();
```

Or change `Box` to have a constructor that takes no arguments and initializes `width` and `length`.

Answer (score 0):

Or you just use your defined constructor and pass the length and width to it...

```
Box myBox = new Box(4,3);
myBox.showBox();
```

and your defined constructor then calls the methods setLength() and setWidth() with your passed int values. (in this case with the values 4 and 3)

Answer (score 0):

When you define a custom constructor the default constructor will no longer be available:
If you want to use it, you should define it explicitly.

You can define two constructors for the following to work

```
Box(int w, int l)
{
    setLength(l);
    setWidth(w);
}

Box()
{
   //this is the default
}
```

You can now use both:

```
new Box()
new Box(w,l)
```